# How to make this specific animation?

Tags: android, animation

I have a `RelativeLayout` which has specific dimensions. I want to make an `Animation` that extends the width of this view to an specific size in 1 second. How would I make such an animation?

Comment: can you say more detail about your problem

Comment: have you scale your relativelayout using animation right?

Comment: it's all in here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html